# recollindex won't recurse into symlinked directories, even with "followLinks=1" and -r

Tags: recursion, symlink, xapian, recoll

If I set "followLinks=1" in recoll.conf, "recollindex" will follow symlinked files and index their contents.

However, if it finds a symlink that's a directory, it will create a single document for the directory, but not recurse into that directory, even if I have "-r" set.

Is there an easy workaround to make recollindex index everything that "find dir -follow" would find?

I can think of some ugly workarounds (including "find dir -follow" itself), but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late in answering this, but, if you are still around, what recoll version are you using ? I've tried from 1.18 to 1.21 and I can't reproduce your issue, I'm seeing "followLinks = 1" working as expected.

jf

Comment: "Recoll version: Recoll 1.19.3 + Xapian 1.2.15". I can show you an example if you still can't get it to (not) work, but can recollindex distinguish between a symlink to a directory and a symlink to a file? It might be because I make symlinks like this "ln -s /tmp test2", not "ln -s /tmp/ test1" (ie, no trailing slash in the target directory). Of course, if that's the only problem, it's an easy fix.